# How to use HTML form validation - pattern attribute?

Tags: html, validation

I can't seem to get the pattern attribute to work for the HTML form validation. I have seen a lot of tutorials and it all says the same and it works for them. Though I am using the same technique as the tutorials, I can't get it to work. For an example, please see the below code.

```
<label for= "firstname" id="firstname">First Name*</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Only Alphabets" required/>
```

I want only alphabets to be inserted into this text box. When I insert numerals, it does ask to match the requested format which is only alphabets. But even when I enter alphabets it shows the message though it is supposed to let me submit the form. I tried all I can but can't seem to find a solution for this due my lack of knowledge. I would really appreciate if you could let me know how to enter only numbers into a field, only alphabets into a field, numbers and alphabets into a field using the pattern attribute for validation. Moreover, I was wondering whether the pattern attribute would be able to help me with this as well. For the National ID text box, I want the user to insert data in a specific format. Like this "A000000". An A in the first followed by 6 digits and if this format is not followed, then to display the message asking to match the requested format. Thank you so much in advance. (Please keep note that I am not using jquery).

```
Edit
```

May I please know how to add ' (apostrophe) along with the alphabets? Moreover pattern="[A-Za-z]+" wont let me insert spaces between words. How do I fix that?

Comment: Wha browser are you using ? Safari doesn't support pattern according to W3Schools

Comment: @Billy: I am using Chrome.

Comment: Your code worked for me, it will let you put in numbers and only tell you when you try to submit the form, You shouldn't need to add the plus sign suggested below. If you want them to only enter numbers then use js and get the keycode on keydown and return false.

Comment: The name and label of your `input` element suggests that you want to read the first name of a person, restricting the name to Ascii letters only. I am sure Jari-Pekka, Åke, René, and Jürgen would find that inappropriate, not to mention Иван and Γιώργιος. It seems that you are not solving the right problem at all.

Comment: I would put `id="firstname"` on the `<input>` element along with `name="firstname"`.  This way, the `for="firstname"` attribute on the `<label>` element will actually have something to point to. If `<label>` needs an id, I would use something like `id="firstname_"`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern field uses regular expressions. Try:

```
pattern="[A-Za-z]+"
```

For the national ID you could use:

```
pattern="A[0-9]{6}"
```

Comment: it worked, thanks you. what if I want only numerals to be entered? is this the way? pattern="[0-9]+" and for both pattern="[A-z][0-9]+" ?

Comment: @SalmanA, I think you should post a correct answer (with references) instead of editing the *substance* of an incorrect answer.

Comment: @F.J I edited my answer to include the national ID regular expression you wanted.

Comment: @SalmanA Could you please explain why that is a wrong answer? It is both valid regexp and works in use?

Comment: The OP's original regexp just needed a `+`. If you changed to to `[A-z]` intentionally then the answer is incorrect, it will match other characters such as `[\]^` (I gave you benefit of doubt instead of -1).